# Slice to Map of pointers duplicates values

Tags: go, pointers, slice, go-map

This is a beginner question about why I get such a result when trying to obtain a Map from a Slice in go lang. I have this code:

```
func (p *ProductsStruct) ToMap() map[int32]*Product {
    result := map[int32]*Product{}

    for _, prod := range p.Products {
        result[prod.ProductId] = &prod
    }

    return result
}
```

ProductsStruct has just a slice of Product and Product struct is as follows

```
type ProductsMedusa struct {
    Products []ProductMedusa
}

type Product struct {
    ProductId    int32
    ProductTitle string
    PriceUSD     float32
}
```

I cannot understand why calling the function ToMap() produces a result with all the keys but pointers to same object: the last. Also, I am aware of the fact that if I don't use map values as pointers, it works fine.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Add `prod := prod` as the first line inside the loop. (i.e., just above `result[prod.ProductId] = &prod`). The reason for the duplicated values is that `for ... range` allocates only its iteration variables (e.g. `prod`) **only once**, it then updates the contents of those variables for each iteration using the corresponding values, but because you are taking the address of that single variable (i.e. `&prod`), you end up, when the loop exits, with all pointers pointing to same address, which stores the last iteration value.

Comment: ... or if you want pointers to the slice elements: `for i, prod := range p.Products { result[prod.ProductId] = &p.Products[i] }`

Comment: In essence this is is what's happening in your code: https://go.dev/play/p/nrpysD5vcDQ

Comment: @CeriseLimón that actually solved my next issue thanks